# highlight all rows that have nan values in panda frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I’ve been trying to highlight all rows that have nan values with the code below:

```
Pd.style.applymap(lambda x: ['background-color: light green' if Pd.isnull() else ''])
```

But this seems doesn’t work. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Styler object has a `highlight_null` function:

```
df.style.highlight_null('lightgreen')
```

[image: Styling with highlight_null]

If you want to change anything other than the background, use `applymap`:

```
df.style.applymap(lambda cell: 'color: red' if np.isnan(cell) else '')
```

[image: Styling with applymap]

If you want to highlight an entire row if any of its columns is null:

```
df.style.apply(lambda row: np.repeat('color: lightgray' if row.isnull().any() else '', row.shape[0]), axis=1)
```

[image: Highlight entire row]

Comment: Thanks Code Different. If I want to highlight the whole row instead of just null cells, what should I do?

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm

Comment: is there a way to set `.style.highlight_null('lightgreen')` for all the dataframe, by default?